# Bazel inside Alpine container issue

Tags: bazel, or-tools

I'm trying to test the build of `google/or-tools` using the **Bazel** based build system on various GNU/Linux distro by using various common distros

When trying to use bazel inside an `Alpine:edge` based Dockerfile (i.e. in a RUN cmd), at "docker build" time.

I don't have a consistency build between my **Archlinux** and on **Github action workflow runners** (ubuntu 18.04 IIRC).
Dockerfile: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/bazel/docker/alpine/Dockerfile

I run it using my Makefile target `alpine_build` in google/or-tools/bazel
ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/bazel/Makefile

From **GH ubuntu-latest** (18.04 LTS ?) runner, I got this trace

```
$ make alpine_build
...
Step 11/11 : RUN bazel build --curses=no --copt='-Wno-sign-compare' //...:all
 ---> Running in 9a2f9b6f24c7
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
DEBUG: Rule 'com_google_protobuf' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments commit = "fe1790ca0df67173702f70d5646b82f48f412b99", shallow_since = "1576187991 -0800"
DEBUG: Call stack for the definition of repository 'com_google_protobuf' which is a git_repository (rule definition at /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:18):
 - /home/lib/WORKSPACE:22:1
Loading: 2 packages loaded
Analyzing: 301 targets (16 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
Analyzing: 301 targets (25 packages loaded, 43 targets configured)
Analyzing: 301 targets (26 packages loaded, 43 targets configured)
...
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/runs/568849544?check_suite_focus=true

So everything seems fine up to this point (still need to figure out the jdk javac issue but it's an other topic)

On the contrary on my **Archlinux**, I've got:

```
$ make alpine_build
...
Step 11/11 : RUN bazel build --curses=no --copt='-Wno-sign-compare' //...:all
 ---> Running in e13ca9fd3e84
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'com_google_protobuf' which is a git_repository (rule definition at /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:18):
 - /home/lib/WORKSPACE:22:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'com_google_protobuf':
   java.io.IOException: unlinkat(/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin) (Directory not empty)
ERROR: no such package '@com_google_protobuf//': java.io.IOException: unlinkat(/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin) (Directory not empty)
ERROR: no such package '@com_google_protobuf//': java.io.IOException: unlinkat(/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin) (Directory not empty)
INFO: Elapsed time: 29.713s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
The command '/bin/sh -c bazel build --curses=no --copt='-Wno-sign-compare' //...:all' returned a non-zero code: 1
make: *** [Makefile:121: alpine_build] Error 1
```

I've tried to look at the file `/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin`
using the previous step (alpine_devel) container:

```
$ make sh_alpine_devel
/home/lib # bazel build --curses=no --copt='-Wno-sign-compare' //...:all
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
Loading:
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
Loading: 0 packages loaded
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'com_google_protobuf' which is a git_repository (rule definition at /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:18):
 - /home/lib/WORKSPACE:22:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'com_google_protobuf':
   java.io.IOException: unlinkat(/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin) (Directory not empty)
ERROR: no such package '@com_google_protobuf//': java.io.IOException: unlinkat(/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin) (Directory not empty)
ERROR: no such package '@com_google_protobuf//': java.io.IOException: unlinkat(/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin) (Directory not empty)
INFO: Elapsed time: 29.924s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
cat /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/86fee77ec27da0053940f3f327a6fd59/external/com_google_protobuf/.git/logs/
refs/remotes/origin/revert-6272-MutableSequence-import
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 c5fedd61a48a174054f98684d5ddbc2d11530367 root <root@Flex2.home> 1586336706 +0000 fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*: storing head
```

note Flex2 is my local machine...

So my questions:

- Is it a known issue (ed don't find anything on java.io.IOException: unlinkat) ?
- Does Bazel deal with the kernel (or uname -a etc...) which could explain why I don't have the same behaviour from one host to an other ?
- May I have more trace to debug this issue ?
- How can I fix it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to tell to bazel to use the java locally installed by alpine than downloading one.

this can be done using the option `--host_javabase=@local_jdk//:jdk`

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/bazel/docker/alpine/Dockerfile#L26

Minimal working example:
https://github.com/Mizux/bazel-cpp/blob/main/ci/docker/alpine/Dockerfile